# Excel VBA Adding Adding Entry to next row

Tags: vba, excel

im kinda new with excel vba, i need some corrections with this one because im getting an error, in short i cant add any data into my next row in excel using userform

This is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ssheet As Worksheet


Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row + 1

ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = CDate(Me.Label1)
ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.ComboBox1
ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.ComboBox2

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `nr = ssheet.Cells(ssheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row + 1` instead of `nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row + 1`. Also, try to code explicitly. So, use `ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = UserForm1.ComboBox1` (or whatever the name is) instead of `ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.ComboBox1`. That's just for the same reason as you are using `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. One question though: is the `UserForm` still showing / loaded when the code is running? Otherwise, the form gets cleaned-out and `ComboBox1` and all the other fields get blanked-out.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: xlUp. xL. L. Not 1, L. Copying code from neighbour student's monitor can produce errors like this...

Comment: I'm voting to close as "Too broad, simple typographical error".

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ssheet As Worksheet

    Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    nr = ssheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = 1
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = 2
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = 3
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think `Range("A1048576")` is any better than `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)`. `xlUp` is certainly better than `x1Up` though.